# Deserializing variable JSON data

Tags: c#, json, .net

In a .NET 4.8 C# application, I'm calling a REST API which returns JSON data as follows:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "perPage": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalRecords": 0
  },
  "links": {
    "first": "https://api.propertyinspect.com/inspections?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "self": "https://api.propertyinspect.com/inspections?page=1",
    "next": null,
    "last": "https://api.propertyinspect.com/inspections?page=1",
  },
  "data": []
}
```

The problem lies in the fact that the third field, "data", is variable, and contains different JSON models depending on which endpoint I've called.
I thought that I could deserialize this model into the following C# class:

```
public class Pagination
{
    public int PerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Prev { get; set; }
    public string Self { get; set; }
    public string Next { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class PIPagination
{
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
    public Link Links { get; set; }
    public ICollection<object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And then, depending on what data type I'm expecting "data" to  hold, I would then cast it to that data type. The problem is that I'm not sure how to do the casting.

For example, when calling a certain endpoint, "data" holds an array of "Client" models. So I tried casting like this:

```
List<Client> clients = pagination.Data.Cast<Client>();
```

and like this:

```
List<Client> clients = List<Client>pagination.Data;
```

but it's not working. Is it even possible to cast from a collection of object to a collection of another type?
Or should I rather create various Pagination classes, one for each type of "data"?

Comment: You are missing a `.ToList()` from your attempts: `List<Client> clients = pagination.Data.Cast<Client>().ToList();` but see Jamiec's answer below!

Comment: If you include the code for `Client` and some example JSON containing sa list of clients I can update my answer with a working example. Also need to know if you're using newtonsoft json or system.text.json

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem statement we can assist with. WHAT is not working? Edit that information into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use generics for this - whereby you can reuse most of your classes, and just have different implementations for `data`

```
public class Pagination
{
    public int PerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Prev { get; set; }
    public string Self { get; set; }
    public string Next { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class PIPagination<TData>
{
    public Pagination Pagination { get; set; }
    public Link Links { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

This way you might implement a class for `Client`, and when you try to deserialize that you use `PIPagination<Client>` as the type.

Comment: That was a great idea! Worked beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you have limited amount of different models then add a constructor for each model like:

if you wanna casts accepted data to `List<PIClient>` then
add into PIClient class

```
PIClient(dynamic model){
   Id = model.id      // or whatever field name is in json
}
```

and then

```
var data = model.Data.Select(x=> new PIClient(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you react_33. I ended up going with Jamiec's suggestion but your suggestion was not a bad one at all - I will keep it in mind.